# javascript on the html created by jinja2 & flask does not work at all

Tags: javascript, flask, jinja2, wsgi

I edit program in flask to manage HTML which contains javascript. when i run the program it runs fine and show the HTML file on the browser(Chrome80.0.3987.122(64bit) on my local pc(windows10). The path to the javascript file on the HTML file is fine and javascript itself runs fine when i make it run locally. when i run this flask program, it shows my html file but the button became inactive and cannot make javascript run. There are no error except '''GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1 404''' Here are the version info: OS: debian 9.8, python3.5.3, jinja2.11.1, Flask1.1.1, Werkzeung1.0.0

Comment: Could you share some relevant code? E.g. the way you handle the button click event, the part where you include the JS file in the template, etc.

Comment: my html code is here. `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="static/js/get_geolocation.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
{{longitude}}
{{latitude}}
<button onclick="test()">test</button>
</body>
</html>`

Comment: my javascript is here `function test() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(test2);
}
function test2(position) {
    var geo_text = "緯度:" + position.coords.latitude + "\n";
    geo_text += "経度:" + position.coords.longitude + "\n";
    geo_text += "位置精度:" + position.coords.accuracy + "\n";
    geo_text += "速度:" + position.coords.speed + "\n";
    var date = new Date(position.timestamp);
    geo_text += "取得時刻:" + date.toLocaleString() + "\n";
    alert(geo_text);
}`

Comment: A couple of questions: (1) When you load the page are you sure that `get_location.js` is successfully loaded? You should use [`url_for()`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/#static-files) to generate absolute URLs. (2) If you open the browser's console can you run `test()` function directly? (3) How do you pass `position` to `test2()`? It seems undefined here.